# How to groupby and sum on similarity of strings

Tags: python, string-matching, fuzzywuzzy

I want to groupby and sum on a dataframe. The standard groupby function groups exactly same strings in rows together but I need this to be done on similar strings. For example-:

```
United States | 10  
Germnay | 23  
Unaited Staetes | 20   
Germany | 21  
Germanny | 32  
Uniited Staites | 30
```

This should result as  -:

```
United States 60  
Germnay 76
```

The order of names are not that important. The sum of the values are.

Thanks a lot :)

EDIT:

Perhaps it would be simpler to create an ID column that gives the same id for similar countries. I can just groupby on that then.

Comment: Please show how you're currently doing it. If that's causing you any issues, besides the gnawing feeling that there may be a better way that we all know so well, please add that in too.

Comment: This seems quite tricky because fuzzy similarity is not necessarily transitive. For example, "dog" is similar to "dig", and "dig" is similar to "wig", but "dog" is not similar to "wig". So how do you decide how to group these words? You don't want "dog" and "wig" in the same group, but you want "dig" to be in the same group as both of them.

Comment: You can use the levenshtein distance for string similarity and set a threshold to like 0.80

Comment: levenshtein is the correct answer but I think it will be very slow because you have to  compare every string to every other string

Comment: this https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4165/computing-the-levenshtein-distance-quickly/4166#4166 maybe of interest to you

Comment: I agree with you. I think the preprocessing solution you proposed is correct.

Comment: Lol Ive corrected myself. I can do it between two strings using fuzz.ratio(string A, string B). I dont know how to do this on a dataframe level that would I guess require itertools etc

Comment: The thing is I can do this if its just grouping similar strings together through this -:

   `for name in test:  
    for g in grs:  
        if all(fuzz.ratio(name, w) > 62 for w in g):  
            g.append(name)  
            break  
    else:  
        grs.append([name, ])  
  
print('output groups:', grs)`  

This prints [United States, Unaeted States, Uniited States],[Germany, Germanny] etc in groups. The issue is I also want to sum the number.

Answer (score 3):

*not the solution but a hack that might help if you are doing something quick and dirty*

1. lowercase the country names
2. remove vowels from the country names
3. remove consecutive occurrences of consonants

after you transform data in this way that you can use normal groupby and it should work pretty well.

I suggest this since your data appears to be country names entered by users.

---

another idea:

preprocessing step:

1. use spelling corrector trained on country names to guess country name from the wrong spelling (https://norvig.com/spell-correct.html)
2. transform each row of the data using that.

then use groupby to group.

Comment: Countries were just an example. I'm using much different strings.

Comment: this should still work the same way if you know what the keys in the resulting table are going to be. you can train on those keys instead of country names.

Comment: I dont know what the keys in the result are going to be. What I do know is that there would always be a lot of similar strings in different rows

Comment: With the quick and dirty approach, Albania and Lebanon both reduce to "lbn". Armenia and Romania both reduce to "rmn". Since OP isn't actually operating on country names, this probably isn't a practical problem, but it demonstrates how a "lossy" approach like this might be prone to group unlike strings.

Comment: @user133442 then you might want to cluster those strings and add up the values for strings that are in the same cluster https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123060/clustering-a-long-list-of-strings-words-into-similarity-groups

Comment: @Kevin aahh good finding! what do you expect from hacks like this LOL :D